# What is the best way to access the old layout.kamada.kawai function?

Tags: r, layout, igraph

With the latest major release of igraph for R (igraph 1.0.0), the function to calculate the **Kamada Kawai layout** was re-written from scratch. The new function (layout_with_kk) seems to produce very different results than the previous function (layout.kamada.kawai) on the same networks (around 4k nodes, 18k edges). Maybe it's a change in the default argument values, or maybe something else.

I'd like to access the old function to figure out what is happening.

Comment: Get the old package version from the [CRAN archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/igraph/).  Don't install it, just unzip it and get the relevant file.

Comment: The old `layout.kamada.kawai` was written in C (and so is the new one) so it's probably not enough to extract the relevant file from the old package - one will also need the corresponding C source files.